# Why don't we wash mayim acharonim on non bread meals?

Tags: hands-fingers, mayim-acharonim

The mishna berurah says that the reason for mayim acharonim is that we are worried about Sodom Salt (even if today's salt is not Sodom Salt, some of it might still be mixed in). He also says that since it's very common to have salt at the meal we must therefore wash mayim acharonim.

If we have salt by most meals wouldn't this require us to wash mayim acharonim even when no bread was eaten (crackers and fish, soups, etc)?